# Plotting a scatter plot in python where the z value corresponds to a color key

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I want to plot a scatter plot where each point has a color that corresponds to the value of a third array.
The colors need to be specific to a key called colors.
So if the z value was 4 then the color should be '#9C6BE1'

```
colors= ["#049FBB", "#5DF10A", "#BF5B3F", "#A95058", "#9C6BE1","#6CC43C","#7B3001", "#B3D407","#97CE66"] #hex colours

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,4,8,6]
z= [4,6,8,2]

plt.scatter(x,y,c=c)
```

How do I plot each point to the color that corresponds to the value for z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use list comprehension and index of the list

```
colors= ["#049FBB", "#5DF10A", "#BF5B3F", "#A95058", "#9C6BE1","#6CC43C","#7B3001", "#B3D407","#97CE66"] #hex colours

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,4,8,6]
z= [4,6,8,2]

plt.scatter(x,y,c=[colors[i] for i in z])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: By using a list comprehension you create a list with the colours you want by using the values in z as index.

```
colors= ["#049FBB", "#5DF10A", "#BF5B3F", "#A95058", "#9C6BE1","#6CC43C","#7B3001", "#B3D407","#97CE66"] #hex colours

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [3,4,8,6]
z= [4,6,8,2]

plt.scatter(x,y,c=[colors[index] for index in z])
```

resulting in this picture

[image]

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed.